# Filter Postgresql query by element value in column containing xml string

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql

I have a `Postgresql` database with a table has a `text` column that contains an `XML` string. Is it possible to parse this string in some form of `SQL` statement so I can filter the query by an element value?

Comment: Why do you store XML as TEXT, when you could store it as XML? And use the XML functions to search.

Comment: The column stores various different message types. Also, I didn't design the db and am not in a position to change it. Just trying to wirk with what I've got.

Comment: so it's not just XML, there are other types of data in there as well?

Comment: Yes but I can filter the data so only the records containing XML are returned. I'd like to filter further and only return records where an element has a certain value.

Answer (score 0):

Are all the XML tags the same with a different value? Is the value the same length? You could try using substring if so.

Here's the docs for pattern matching if not https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html

You could also use xpath

So if your xml reads like this

```
<item>
    <name>Screwdriver</name>
    <supplier>Bob's Massive Tools</supplier>
    <price>60</price>
</item>
```

Then

```
SELECT 
    xpath('/item/name/text()', xml_content) AS name,
    xpath('/item/supplier/text()', xml_content) AS supplier,
    xpath('/item/price/text()', xml_content) AS price
FROM 
    xml_data;
```

should work